# Codeigniter Url without index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, iis-8.5

I want to create a app url 'http://example.com'. But entering the url, it shows 'HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden'. when i have inserted 'index.php' at the last of url like 'http://example.com/index.php' the landing page is rendering in the browser
I have changed the

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

in config.php file. Then i have placed the .htaccess file in the codeigniter root folder along with application and system folder. Then in the .htaccess file i have coded with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I just want to remove the 'index.php' from the url. I am using IIS 8.5 web server.

Comment: Have you written any code? if yes then post it.

Answer (score 0):

In CI you can set session data when login is successful:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username' $this->input->post('username'))
```

you can unset at logout

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

and use database for sessions:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I want a third party library which has better session functions